# Round-trip passing of data from Javascript to Redis (via Python) and back?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, redis

I'm refactoring a project that I've used as a learning tool for myself, that is a HTML5 canvas game, where I have a hexagonal grid of tiles built with javascript objects and canvas. Everything is stored in a javascript object structure.

I'm trying to learn more about Python. I set up a basic Python Flask route, was able to POST an AJAX request from the javascript to the Flask route, was able to submit to Redis, was able to retrieve from Redis... but I can't seem to figure out what piece I'm missing for passing the information from Python back to the javascript object.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <script type=text/javascript src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery-2.2.0.min.js') }}"></script>

</head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
    var data = 
        {
            row: '3',
            col: '3',
        };
    $('#sendBtn').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/saveMap',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response.row)
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<body>
    <button id="sendBtn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button">Send</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Python:
    from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
    import redis

```
app = Flask(__name__)
r = redis.Redis("localhost")

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/saveMap',methods=['POST'])
def saveMap():
    if request.method == "POST":
        r.set("test", request.json)
        result = r.get("test")
        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

So, when clicking the #sendBtn, the request goes through, comes back, shows up as a response in the Network tab as

```
{u'col': u'3', u'row': u'3'}
```

but within the success part of the AJAX call, when I try to call response.row, it gives me an "undefined".

I feel like I'm so close, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `r.get("test")` returns a `str` that *looks* like a dict. Using `jsonify`, `pickle.dumps`, and `pickle.loads` will solve your problem.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import redis, pickle

app = Flask(__name__)
r = redis.Redis("localhost")

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/saveMap',methods=['POST'])
def saveMap():
    if request.method == "POST":
        r.set("test", pickle.dumps(request.json))
        result = pickle.loads(r.get("test"))
        return jsonify(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

edit: changed from using `eval` to using `pickle` just to be safe as reptilicus mentioned

Comment: This is a far better answer than the random string manipulation solution I was doing in the above answer.  This even makes it so that that receiving javascript doesn't even need to JSON.parse() the object, it just immediately comes in as a javascript object.   Thanks a lot!

Comment: never ever ever use `eval` in a web application, way too many attack vectors there...

Comment: fair enough. edited to use `pickle` instead of `eval`

Answer (score 0):

Try `console.log(response)` to see what's actually coming back. If it is JSON getting returned, you may still need to parse it before you can access it like an object, and it may be getting wrapped somehow depending on whether there's middleware involved in your server processing.

Comment: This yields `{u'col': u'3', u'row': u'3'}` in the console. I further did a `console.log(typeof(response))` and got back `string`. Sooo... it's a string that looks like JSON.

Comment: Right. You'll need to parse it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Also, if I do a `JSON.parse(repsonse)` I'm getting this error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`   So, is it somehow malformed JSON?

Comment: The 'u' may be a problem. Check your server to make sure it's trying to send back serialized JSON (possibly via `json.dumps`) and not a Python string representation of a dictionary.

Comment: Your answer isn't quite right, but it led me down the right path. 

It turns out that `JSON.parse()` doesn't like those `u` characters AND it prefers double-quotes to single. So, I had to do the following to get it to work:
    `response = response.replace(/u/g, "");
    response = response.slice(1, response.length - 1);
    response = response.replace(/'/g, '"');

    var responseJSON = JSON.parse(response);`

Comment: I still think somehow you're getting a Python string representation instead of an actual JSON dump. The `u'...'` notation is not something any sane JSON parser will output; I'd suggest looking into that further. I'm glad you got it working, but in your position, I'd definitely look into why that's happening rather than regexing it.